# PHP Functions to Increment Classic Software Version Numbers?

Tags: php, version

I am looking for PHP functions that can increment classic software version numbers...

Example

```
<?php

$a_version_number = '3.1.2';

$c = version_increment($a_version_number);
echo 'Next Version: ' . $c . "\n";
```

Any ideas on where I can find functions that would do what I am looking to do?

Comment: Why don't you write one on your own?

Comment: since you can not know what the last version was, without defaulting to a static number, I am guessing a version_increment is really the only thing viable from this question

Comment: Reason I didn't immediately write my own is simple, I was told once, that a great programmer uses other peoples code... also, by seeing other peoples code, I can get a broader view of how people code differently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a single function that will do both. If the second argument is a positive number, it will increment. If it's a negative number, it will decrement:

```
function version_update($i, $inc_dec){
    $a = explode('.', $i);
    if($inc_dec > 0){
        $a[count($a)-1]++;
    } elseif ($inc_dec < 0){
        $a[count($a)-1]--;
    }
    return implode('.', $a); 
}

$b = version_update($a_version_number, -1);
echo 'Previous Version: ' . $b . "\n";

$c = version_update($a_version_number, 1);
echo 'Next Version: ' . $c . "\n";
```

Comment: if ($a[count($a)-1] < 0) $a[count($a)-1] = 0;  <- Add this code after  $a[count($a)-1]--;

Answer (score 3):

Years ago, I writed this function. Silly and somewhat limited, but it works:

```
function increment_version($version)
{
    $parts = explode('.', $version);

    if ($parts[2] + 1 < 99) {
        $parts[2]++;
    } else {
        $parts[2] = 0;
        if ($parts[1] + 1 < 99) {
            $parts[1]++;
        } else {
            $parts[1] = 0;
            $parts[0]++;        
        }
    }

    return implode('.', $parts);
}
```

Examples:

```
increment_version('1.2.3');      // output: 1.2.4
increment_version('1.2.99');     // output: 1.3.0
increment_version('1.99.99');    // output: 2.0.0
increment_version('99.99.99');   // output: 100.0.0
```

I dont have a decrement version, but should be easy to implement.